# ./node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/cookies.js Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, axios

I'm trying to simply use an api but it's giving me this error. I've tried all possible solutions out there still nothing.

im running this as admin and it's windows 10
firewall antivirus is off
tired uninstalling and installing npm
tried npm cache clean --force command too
tired deselecting read-only if node_modules property.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Clarifai from "clarifai";
import ImageSearchForm from "./components/ImageSearchForm/ImageSearchForm";
import FaceDetect from "./components/FaceDetect/FaceDetect";
import "./App.css";

// You need to add your own API key here from Clarifai.
const app = new Clarifai.App({
  apiKey: "My api xxx",
});

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      input: "",
      imageUrl: "",
      box: {},
    };
  }

  calculateFaceLocation = (data) => {
    const clarifaiFace =
      data.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box;
    const image = document.getElementById("inputimage");
    const width = Number(image.width);
    const height = Number(image.height);
    return {
      leftCol: clarifaiFace.left_col * width,
      topRow: clarifaiFace.top_row * height,
      rightCol: width - clarifaiFace.right_col * width,
      bottomRow: height - clarifaiFace.bottom_row * height,
    };
  };

  displayFaceBox = (box) => {
    this.setState({ box: box });
  };

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ input: event.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({ imageUrl: this.state.input });
    app.models
      .predict(Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL, this.state.input)
      .then((response) =>
        this.displayFaceBox(this.calculateFaceLocation(response))
      )
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ImageSearchForm
          onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
        />
        <FaceDetect box={this.state.box} imageUrl={this.state.imageUrl} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```